# AVERAGEIFS FORMULA

Tags: excel

I need help to calculate a formula using AVERAGEIFS. I have never used it before and I was wondering how to use it in simple terms.
[EXAMPLE OF DATA I NEED TO CALCULATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Br8u.jpg)

I need a formula that adds up the average of team ECC222 for week 13/04/2014. Any advice?

C

Comment: Just to clarify.  You say in your question you want to ADD UP the averages.  this implies the averages are being supplied.  You need to do a SUMIF to add things that meet a criteria or SUMIFS if you have multiple criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$4:$A$13,"ECC222",$B$4:$B$13)
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help. If it solved your problem kindly mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you type the formula `=AVERAGEIFS(` into Excel, it tells you the syntax of the formula. The first entry is the range you want an average of, the second is the criteria you want to put your if statement against, the third is the second criteria you want to compare and so on.

I'm not able to access your link to provide more information at this point.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more dynamic, as in you can have two cells one that have the Team Name and the other the date, you can use this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(INDEX(($A$2:$A$11=H1)*($B$1:$E$1=H2),)>0,B2:E11))
```

Being an Array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter or Tab or Clicking out of the cell.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]